# VS2010 VC++ cannot find executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to figure what the issue is with VS2010 not finding the executable i just built. When I hit F5 to execute it pops up an error saying it cannot find the executable.

Wouldn't that be under `Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Output file`?

Why doesn't VS just execute whatever that path is? I'm confused. What am I missing?

Would really appreciate somebody helping me understand how this works in VS.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding it?

Comment: Forgetting to review the Error List and fixing the errors is a traditional mistake.  Practice using Build + Build for a while.

Comment: Did you select `Relase` build mode actually?

Comment: I realise you say executable, but I assume you're not building a .DLL? If you are, then you'll get something like this when you try to run it, as you need a "host" (a .exe for example).

Comment: I would start with verifying that the build succeeded. Build again. If there are no errors then check if the executable exists. If you don't know the exact folder search inside your project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it.

PenkajM's answer helped lead me to the resolution. To add to that answer, `Output Directory` is mapped to `$(OutDir)` macro. But under `Linker->General->Output File` I used the `$(OutDir)` macro and added to that path something like `$(OutDir)\..\bin\$(Configuration)\myapp.exe`.

This caused the build to put create the exe in one place but when running it VS looked for the executable in another place.

The solution was to modify `Output Directory` under `General` to what I want, then under `Linker->General->Output File` set it to `$(OutDir)\myapp.exe`

Answer (score 1):

You have to change
Configuration properties -> General -> Output Directory,
Configuration properties -> General -> Target Name
and
Configuration properties -> General -> Target Extension

Comment: Yes, visual studio IDE picks application path from this location when you hit F5